# Javascript Load More Data on Click in Codeigniter results not displaying

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have products in table I wish to display some when page load and remain data should display on button click, I have set limit as 6 per page, when page loading it is displaying first six rows and if I click on Load More button it is displaying another six rows here problem coming after got 12 rows from table when I click again on Load More button it is not working even I have more data in table, I have cross checked parameters also, it is fine parameters also sending with request. please help me how to solve this.

NOTE: when I test this script in core php it is working fine, when I implement this script in codeigniter first time click load more data working second time when i click it is not wokring.

Javascript Code Block

```
$('.more').click(function(){
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var cats = $('input[name=cats]').val();
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="<?=ROOT;?>resources/moreajax.gif" />');
$.post('<?=ROOT;?>product/dataLoad', {id:ID,cats:cats}, function(data){
    if(data)
    {
    $('ol#updates').append(data);
    $("#more"+ID).remove();
        }
    else
    {
    $(".morebox").html('The End');// no results
    }

});
return false;
});
```

codeigniter controller function

```
public function dataLoad() {
        if(isset($_POST['id']))
        {
        $lastmsg=$_POST['id'];
        $cats = $_POST['cats'];
        $query=mysql_query("select * from product where id > '".$lastmsg."' AND category_id IN ($cats) order by id asc limit 4");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        while($ob = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        ?>
        <div>
        <p>ID: <?=$ob['id']; </p>
        <p>NAME: <?=$ob['name']; </p>
        </div>
        <?php
        }//while
        ?>
        <?php
        if($numrows > 0)
        {
        ?>
        <div id="more<?php echo $ob['id']; ?>" class="morebox" style="clear:both">
        <input type="hidden" name="cats" value="<?=$cats;?>" />
        <a href="#" class="more" id="<?=$ob['id'];?>">Load More</a>
        </div>
        <?php
        }

     }
        ?>
```

product page code

```
<ol class="timeline" id="updates">
    $str = implode(",",$cats);
            $query = "select * FROM product WHERE category_id IN (".$str.")         order by id asc limit 4";
            $result=mysql_query($query);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            while($ob = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            ?>
            <div>
            <p>ID: <?=$ob['id']; </p>
            <p>NAME: <?=$ob['name']; </p>
            </div>
            <?php
            }//while
            ?>
    </ol>
            <?php
            if($numrows > 0)
            {
            ?>
            <div id="more<?php echo $ob['id']; ?>" class="morebox" style="clear:both">
            <input type="hidden" name="cats" value="<?=$cats;?>" />
            <a href="#" class="more" id="<?=$ob['id'];?>">Load More</a>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: I thought error in javascript #more"+ID not clearing values properly

Comment: 4 hours still no response from any one

Comment: 30 hours over still no response is nobody there who know javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem insted of this

```
$('.more').click(function(){

$("#updates").on("click",".more",function(){
```